# Where is my Syntax Error, and how can i join them

Tags: php

```
    $tweet = $row['pledge'] $row['fname'];
{
echo "$tweet";
}
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: You can remove the braces too, they aren't doing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Use [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) operpator

```
  $tweet = $row['pledge'].$row['fname'];
  {
     echo "$tweet";
  }
```

Comment: @ADMob It's also interesting to note that you can do this with both `$tweet = $row['pledge'].$row['fname'];` or this `$tweet = $row['pledge'] . $row['fname'];`. The only difference being the spaces either side of the concatenation operator. I personally use spaces for readability, but it's all down to personal preference.

Comment: Thank you guys, you are great! I finally achieved what i wanted through everyone's help here. I can now have form to twitter script

Answer (score 0):

```
$tweet = $row['pledge'] . $row['fname'];
```

Now ECHO

```
echo $tweet;
```